# How to kill this app in android or restart

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kill-process

I'm trying to kill or restart This app so i can refresh the url list when json parse,,
This app doesn't have a launcher and cannot be launched directly :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iptvremote.android.iptv.core&hl=en

I'm using this code but didn't work, also I did the permissin in android manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    jsonParse();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("ru.iptvremote.android.iptv.core")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "app  killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("ru.iptvremote.android.iptv.core");               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked well for me

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(startMain);
        am.killBackgroundProcesses("put app package name here ");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Process Killed : " + _put app package name here , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill your app like this;

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

If you want to restart;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: ahmet koçu  
I don't want to kill my app  I need to kill another app

Comment: oh ok. This should work `activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("ru.iptvremote.android.iptv.core");
`

Comment: ahmet koçu Not work  I did that before you can find it in the code above :(